# Python - psycopg2 IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following PGSQL request :

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(invoices.id)) as total FROM invoices LEFT JOIN status ON invoices.status = status.id  LEFT JOIN suppliers ON invoices.vatNumber = suppliers.vatNumber  WHERE to_char(registerDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = %s AND invoices.status = 'NEW'
```

With this data :

```
['2020-07-28']
```

If I run (with replacement of %s) directly on postgres console, it works

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(invoices.id)) as total FROM invoices LEFT JOIN status ON invoices.status = status.id  LEFT JOIN suppliers ON invoices.vatNumber = suppliers.vatNumber  WHERE to_char(registerDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2020-07-28' AND invoices.status = 'NEW'
```

But if I run it like this using psycopg2 I have a `IndexError: list index out of range`  error:

```
query = "SELECT count(DISTINCT(invoices.id)) as total FROM invoices LEFT JOIN status ON invoices.status = status.id  LEFT JOIN suppliers ON invoices.vatNumber = suppliers.vatNumber  WHERE to_char(registerDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = %s AND invoices.status = '"
c = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
c.execute(query, args['data'])
```

Any idea ?

EDIT :

The same code with different request, works perfectly... :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s
```

With data :

```
[1]
```

Comment: The second parameter to `execute` is supposed to be a tuple.  e.g. `c.execute(query, (args['data'], ))`  (and yes, that extra comma needs to be there).

Comment: If I did that I have an error from another request (before the one I mention in my post) : 

`psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ARRAY[1] 
`

Comment: Sorry.  I did not see that `args['data']` is a list.  Please try this:  `c.execute(query, tuple(args['data']))`

Comment: Now I have `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.... But I don't undestand why it's not working with this request but another one works (I edit my first post)

Comment: It's the `%Y-%m-%d` that's causing this.  It's supposed to be `to_char(registerDate, 'YYYY-mm-dd')`, but you should use `registerDate::date`.  If you use the `%` character in a parameterized query, then you need to escape it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks :)